# How to count Characters and printing the count

Tags: java, exception

Write a class with a static method that accepts characters one at a time, counts the number of characters, and throws an exception if a character is not in the set { 'a'..'z', '0'..'9', 'A'..'Z'  }. The exception should be thrown but not caught (i.e., no explicit catch  block). Write a client program that calls this method and prints “Error in Input” if the method throws an exception.

My Question is, how to count the input characters and print them?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Format {

    public static int countChars(char c) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;


        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            throw new Exception("Input Error");
        }

        return count;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = ' ';
        int length = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a String: ");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    try{
                    countChars(line.charAt(i));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Wrong Character");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  //  System.out.println("Count: " + count);
}
```

Comment: User has to input the characters for the set

Comment: In that case, your `countChars` method has to be passed the set. What type of "set" do you want?

Comment: WHat is your actual problem?  (And what is your countChars method intended to do?)

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to accept characters one by one, you'll need a variable outside of the `countChars` function. As you're not using an object but only static functions, that variable should be static too. So, something like this:

```
private static int length = 0;

public static int countChars(char c) throws Exception {
  length++;
  //...
}
```

You can then access the variable length from the main function too.

Answer (score 0):

`Char` can only hold one character. A `String` is holding a whole sequence of characters.

As it happens a `String` has a method called `length()`. ;)